# handling error messages in action class

Tags: java, error-handling, struts, action

I have a scenario where a particular method has a error message but it also returns a boolean and down the code there is another method specific to display error messages and it is initialised to action errors. something like foll.

```
if(abc())
{
form.set(soemthing...);
}
///
///
errors = validate();

if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
saveErrors(request, errors);

public boolean abc()
{
////
errors.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_ERROR, ....
return true;
}
```

From above code function abc() returns an error but since down the code errors are again set to someother value the error from abc is not getting printed. I cant put all the validations in a single method because of another constraint. How do i handle this and disaply error message in abc().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like:

```
public object validate(List<Error> errors) {
    /*some code*/
    error.add(/*error generated in here*/);
}
```

this way you dont get a new instance of errors when validate is called